# ExpressJS - Use different path for views depending on user

Tags: express

I have an Angular app using i18n and Angular CLI. The CLI creates an application (and a different folder) for each language. I'd like to render views depending on the user session (his/her language preference is in his/her session).

Here is the structure of my folders

```
myapp
--dist
----en
----fr
```

So I wanted to set the view folder to:

```
app.set('views', join(__dirname, 'dist'));
```

and then redirect the user to its language folder. Is it a correct strategy and if it is, how can I redirect the user to its folder (for views only)?

Answer (score 1):

If we have configured Express as follows:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'/views'));
```

And if you had the following file structure:

```
/views/
/views/en/welcome.html
/views/fr/welcome.html
/views/en/news/article1.html
/views/fr/news/article1.html
```

You need to write a middleware that gets preferred language from the session, sets `req.body.preferredLang` to some value and calls `next()` in the end of it.

And then use that middleware in your app.js like this:

```
app.use(languageMiddleware);
```

Finally you can render like this:

```
router.get('/welcome', (req, res, next) => { 
    res.render(`${req.body.preferredLang}/welcome`, {}); 
});
```

Comment: Angular compiles the files and creates a folder for each language. That's how Angular i18n works (https://angular.io/guide/i18n)! I'm not talking about i18n of Express...

Comment: My question is how do you set the view path depending on the user session!

Comment: Uhh. Sorry for that. As far as I experienced, we use something like the updated answer. But that does not include sessions of course. I am gonna edit the answer if I find a solution. @ncohen

Comment: @ncohen What do you use for sessions though? passport.js ?

Comment: You don't get the point... I don't want the language to appear in the URL

Comment: @ncohen I get it but setting different views is not possible in run-time. (decision made by the session or token)

Comment: The path of `app.set('views', path)` must be a string... how can I make it dynamic and depending on the request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162029/discussion-between-ncohen-and-gokcand).

Comment: @ncohen As I said so, it is impossible. But you can eliminate the lang tag in the urls I think.